# PowerPC G4 graphics adapter ATI RV350 [Mobility Radeon 9600 M10] driver is unclaimed

Tags: drivers, graphics, video, radeon, amd-graphics

ATI RV350 [Mobility Radeon 9600 M10]

This is a fresh install of Ubuntu, and `sysinfo` says the driver for this is unclaimed.

I think I need the xorg xserver radeon drivers, but I never know if I am typing in the right commands or not.

What do I need to do?

Comment: What is the problem? What does not work?

Comment: I don't have a driver installed, and so showing the screen and doing basic tasks is quite laggy.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Power pc version 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I fixed the pixels and bad color with

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati
```

Hopefully that can help someone.